# Using not and and operator in condition mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use the And and not operator in following rewrite conditions.

Can some one tell me whether they are valid wrt syntax or not

```
1.RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !android&!blackberry&!iphone&!ipod&!iemobile [NC]

2.RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile) [NC]
```

Logically both are same but I am not sure if we can use & and ! operators in conditions

Comment: 2nd syntax is valid one.

Comment: @anubhava   Thank you. Does ! indicates not condition. I want to check not of android etc. Can you please confirm. Can you also tell do I need to use ^,., $ in above conditions.

Comment: You shouldn't use `^` and `$` since `USER_AGENT` can have some extra fluff also. And yes 2nd condition does mean something like: `if ( USER_AGENT != "android" && USER_AGENT != "iphone" && USER_AGENT != "blackberry" )`

Comment: Thank you so much. It think it check if( !User_Agent.contains(Android) etc right.

Comment: yes that's correct `USER_AGENT.contains("android")` is much better way to put it.